# Criteria Query JPA : insert into select

Tags: jpa, eclipselink, criteriaquery

Is it possible to do the following SQL query with CriteriaQuery (EclipseLink) ?

> INSERT INTO my_table (SELECT columns FROM other_table)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

No. All possible modes of Criteria (SELECT, UPDATE, DELETE) are shown on this page
http://www.datanucleus.org/products/accessplatform_4_0/jpa/jpql_criteria.html

Comment: This link is no longer available.